# Virtual Harddisk LED in the Panel

Tags: unity, hard-drive, indicator

With my PC out of my sight I'm happy to have a very silent System with no Sound whatsoever, even not from HardDisk.

BUT this can be a hazard if you want to know about activity of the Disc.
So, I'm looking for a simple LED in the Panel in the first step and the same with different LED's for different Partitions.

I searched quite a lot and found some solutions for MS's Windows, but since I don't like Win.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install `indicator-multiload`:

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-multiload
```

Run it from the dash, and it will appear in the bar at the top.  Right click on it, select **Preferences**, uncheck **Processor** (if you wish) and check **Hard disk**.

It shows usage over time (rather than an LED-style indicator) and doesn't separate out individual disks.

[Source](http://www.howtogeek.com/118908/10-awesome-indicator-applets-for-ubuntus-unity-desktop/)

Comment: this does the job for indication of HD Activity plus an slight hint on the amount of data. Nice Job and easy to handle with detailed selection of the resource and choosing colors aso.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't Conky do the trick? It can display anything you want in almost any form you can imagine.

It's only that it draws on desktop and not in Panel.

Comment: yes, a mighty tool, but it will take some time to come into the mysteries of configuration, will try that later.